# Web scraping of all stock key stats from Finviz with R

Tags: r

As I am new to scraping, I would like to ask the question how I could scrape all tickets (stocks) and a couple of key stats, based on my wishes, from FinViz and save the output in a .csv or .xls file (stocks in each row and key stats in columns)?

Comment: SO is not a code-translation service. We're not here to do your projects for you. There are online coding-for-hire facilities for questions such as this.

Comment: @42- I don't ask for code-translation but how to scrape key stats.

Comment: Stack Overflow is for asking *specific* programming questions, not general "How do I...", there are plenty of answered questions on using R as a web scraping tool. Also see [How to make a great reproducible example in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

You could use the quantmod package in R to save the historical data to a .csv file. Why do you want to use FinViz in particular?

Comment: thank you for your response. I do not want to use FinViz specifically. I am alright with YahooFinance, GoogleFinance or some other alternative. However, the main goal is to at least scrape all available symbols instead of a couple of..